# How do I find the name of my development database? (PostgreSQL/Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, heroku

I am tweaking a bash script I found somewhere for downloading the contents of your database on Heroku and the importing them into your development environment.

```
#!/bin/bash
heroku pgbackups:capture --expire --app testivate
file_path="db_$(date +%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S).dump"
curl `heroku pgbackups:url --app testivate` > $file_path
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U steven -d DATABASENAME $file_path
```

My question is, is there a command I can run to find the name of my development database?

In `/config/database.yml` I have:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/testivate_development
  pool: 5
  username: steven
  password: <redacted>
  host: localhost
```

So as my name I've tried "steven", "db/testivate_development" and "testivate_development", but all give "database does not exist" errors.

Comment: Is it possible that the database has not been created yet?

Comment: possibly -- i seem to have been able to import it now using db/testivate_development as the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I suggest you use the pg:transfer heroku client plugin. https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer

This lets you do:

```
heroku pg:transfer --from VIOLET
```

In your project folder you have a .env file which contains

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://127.0.0.1/development_db_name
```

it wraps up the capture, restore for you. VIOLET is the name of the DB url on Heroku (From `heroku config`. The rest should be self explanatory.

Comment: hmmm... just one flag means the difference b/w pulling my heroku database to localhost and pushing my localhost database to heroku! might not trust my fat fingers with that kind of power

Comment: it asks for confirmation :)

Comment: oh, ok -- i'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

There's documentation on this page that shows how to find out this information.  Heroku doesn't use your db name from the config file, it creates its own name and password which is basically random strings.

Comment: sorry, i meant the name of my development database on localhost